# How did I open the MathJax menu in Safari (on iPhone)

Tags: support, mathjax

I was viewing a post on my iPhone (in Safari) which had some MathJax equations, and I accidentally clicked on an equation and opened its MathJax menu:

---

[image: MathJax menu]

---

Anyone know how I did that?

I can’t seem to find a consistent method to repeat it (though I can get it to open sometimes with a random volley of frustrated taps).

**Test Equation**
$$\text{Menu}=C_a*T (t_n, t_d) $$

*where* \$C_a\$ *is the coefficient of annoyance*,
\$T\$ *is the tap sequence as a function of the number of taps* \$t_n\$, *and the tap delay* \$t_d\$.

Comment: On PC, right-clicking the equation will open the MathJax menu. Perhaps the equivalent of long-pressing the equation on touch-screen devices?

Comment: @AndrewT. For me, that just ends up selecting some of the equation’s text. I tried doing so with various pressures as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the contextual menu on a mobile device, use "double-tap-and-hold", which is a tap followed quickly by a second (long) tap where you continue to hold down until the menu opens.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Well, it doesn’t work in the SE app (which still runs in some compatibility mode, as it hasn’t been updated in years).